# Solr Date Range Facets not returning results till current date

Tags: solr

So my Solr date range query is as follows:

```
&facet.range=date&facet.range.start=NOW/DAY-36MONTH&facet.range.end=NOW/MONTH&facet.range.gap=%2B1MONTH
```

However the facets I am getting for the date is till last month, say today is 23rd December and I am getting it till 23rd November. How should I modify my query to obtain results till today?

Answer (score 1):

So the correct portion of the query is in BOLD &facet.range=date&facet.range.start=NOW/DAY-36MONTH&facet.range.end=**NOW/MONTH+1MONTH**&facet.range.gap=%2B1MONTH

Note that + has to be escaped.